# Replace German keyboard of Macbook Pro MC700

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a German Macbook Pro, but I dont really like the keyboard layout, I would like to replace about 15 keys to make it easier for typing. Is it possible to do so ? And where can I find the black cover of the key (Do I need to buy the white scissors below the black cover as well ???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the entire keyboard. See how to [tear down macbook pro unibody](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Teardown/590/1).